# Is there any way to render a complete webpage as a component in react application?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On click of a button say href to "youtube.com", can we render this complete redirected page **within a component** using react-route?

Answer (score 0):

Create one Component in your application to load this webpage. In that Component place below code.

```
<iframe src="placeyourdestinationpath"} id="iframe-style"> </iframe>
```

You can achieve your target by this.